# GNU standard library naming conventions

Tags: gcc, gnu, styling, libstdc++

When I'm looking at the implementation of GNU libraries (well, libstdc++ mostly), I can see that there are recurring patterns in naming. Template types are named `_Tp`, members have prepending `_M_`, some tokens have prepending double underscores, etc. I tried to find documentation on naming conventions to no avail. GNU has a styling guide, which is also followed in the code, but is more like a subset of this naming convention.

Do you know any documentation on styling specifics of GNU gcc library implementations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underscores are not a "coding convention" but rather there to avoid name clashes with user defined macros etc.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html (this is actually for libc, but I assume it holds for libstdc++ as well):

> In addition to the names documented in this manual, reserved names
> include all external identifiers (global functions and variables) that
> begin with an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use
> that begin with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a
> capital letter are reserved names. This is so that the library and
> header files can define functions, variables, and macros for internal
> purposes without risk of conflict with names in user programs.

The GNU website also provides more information on further reserved names.
Also see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) question. It looks like the C++ standard itself dictates the naming conventions.

**Update:**

The information requested by the OP seems to be a little scattered across different pages. I will try to summarize the most important points below:

First of all, information regarding names like `_T` or `_M_` can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/source_code_style.html).

Excerpt:

> For nonstandard names appearing in Standard headers, we are
> constrained to use names that begin with underscores. This is called
> "uglification". The convention is: [...]
>
> Type names and template formal-argument names: _[A-Z][^_].*
>
> Examples:  _Helper  _CharT  _N
>
> Member data and function names: _M_.*
>
> Examples:  _M_num_elements  _M_initialize ()
>
> Static data members, constants, and enumerations: _S_.*
>
> Examples: _S_max_elements  _S_default_value

Further digging led me to the [libstdc++ contributing page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/appendix_contributing.html), where it says:

> The GNU C++ Library is part of GCC and follows the same development
> model, so the general rules [for contributing to GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/contribute.html) apply.

Following above link, you will reach the GNU GCC contributing page, where it reads (under Coding Standards)

> All contributions must conform to the GNU Coding Standards. There are
> also some additional coding conventions for GCC; these include
> documentation and testsuite requirements as well as requirements on
> code formatting.
>
> Submissions which do not conform to the standards will be returned
> with a request to address any such problems. To help with the
> preparation of patches you can use the script
> [contrib/check_GNU_style.sh](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=contrib/check_GNU_style.sh).

This will eventually lead to the [GCC Coding Conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/codingconventions.html), which is a general guideline.

I hope this provides some better information.

Comment: This does not precisely answer the question, but provides a good place to start nontheless.

Comment: Edit: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for :) Marking it as answer.